# MS SQL Studio error checking constraint expression

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've created a simple table with *UserDate* column of DateTime type. I'm trying to add a constraint via Constraint Expression dialog box in SSMS. It should be not null with the default value from getdate function. I enter the following expression:

```
DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [UserDate]
```

But it prompts me with error:

> Error validating <the_name_of_constraint>

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the full SQL you're executing to add the constraint, along with the full error message.

Comment: Honestly, just don't use the designer; it lacks functionality, is quirky and buggy. Use T-SQL to add your constraints, or (in fact) perform any of your DDL and DML statements.

Comment: @RichardDeeming This is the full expression in my question: DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [UserDate] placed into SSMS constraint designer.

Comment: @Larnu Agree, just wanted to know why it does not work in designer..

Comment: As far as I can see, the constraint designer is for check constraints, not defaults. You can specify a default value in the column properties, but you can't give it a constraint name - you'd just enter `getdate()` as the default value. As Larnu said, [use T-SQL to add the constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure) instead.